# Parsing map JSON value and reinserting back into map

Tags: java, json, parsing, hashmap, gson

I am trying to parse a map and update the value in it...
Here is the content of the .txt file that I have made the hashmap

The first line is the key and the JSON string is the value.

```
Not_enough_parameters
{"status": false, "errorMessage": "Payload has incorrect amount of parts: expecting: 18, actual:8", "version": "0.97", "coreName": "Patient_Responsibility"}
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
parse = params.split("\\|"); 
        String key;
        String value;
        String value2;
        String key2;
        String value3;
        Map<String, String> predictionFeatureMap = mockconfig.getPredictionFeatureMap();

        if(parse.length!=18) {

            key = "Not_enough_parameters";
            value = predictionFeatureMap.get(key);
            Map<?,?> resultJsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(value, Map.class);
            key2 = "errorMessage";
            value2 = (String) resultJsonObj.get(key2);
            value3 = value2.substring(0,61) +parse.length+value2.substring(62);
            }
```

I am sending a payload string named params that is separated by "|" separators. They input must have 18 parameters(18 values in-between the "|" separators). I parse the input and if it does not have enough parameters I get they key containing the string "Not_enough_paramters" and then get its value which is the JSON string.

I then take that JSON string and using Gson create a map out of it.

I did that because I want value to return

```
{"status": false, "errorMessage": "Payload has incorrect amount of parts: expecting: 18, actual:(params.length)", "version": "0.97", "coreName": "Patient_Responsibility"}
```

So I want "actual:" to be updated. I get the value from the JSON map for "errorMessage" and using substring I get the index and change the value to update the actual amount of parameters the user put in.

I am not sure how to reinsert the new JSON into the entire JSON string in the JSON map  and then into the original map.

Comment: Firstly you need not to convert a string to map just to replace a parameter, you can achieve this by using string .replace() method and regx. Second don't update your original map because it will override your exception template create a copy of your original map and replace your key with new string and return new map

Comment: @RaviTeja Hey, I implemented a solution and got it working...Not sure if it is efficient though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I implemented a solution although I am not sure it is the cleanest and most straight forward.

I still got the substring from the value from the "errorMessage" key in the JSON Map.

I then replaced the value of that key with the new edited JSON.

Then I took the Json Map and converted it into a string.

I then added the new JSON string to the value of the original hashmap

```
String[] parse;
    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public String payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
        LOGGER.debug("code is hitting");
        String key,key2;
       String value,value2,value3;
        Map<String, String> predictionFeatureMap = mockconfig.getPredictionFeatureMap();
        if(parse.length!=18) {

            key = "Not_enough_parameters";
            value = predictionFeatureMap.get(key);
            Map<String,Object> resultJsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(value, Map.class);
            key2 = "errorMessage";
            value2 = (String) resultJsonObj.get(key2);
            value3 = value2.substring(0,61) +parse.length+value2.substring(62);
            resultJsonObj.replace(key2, value3);
            String updatedResponse = new Gson().toJson(resultJsonObj,Map.class);  
            value = updatedResponse;

            }
        else {
            key = params;
            value = predictionFeatureMap.get(key);
        }
        return value;
```